# Clear android build cache after every build

Tags: android, cordova, caching, meteor

I have multiple apps i am developing and i want to clear cache after every specific build because i realize that the same app is getting built over and over again even the code resides in a different directory.

This is my build command

```
meteor build ~/mydir --server=https://lagoon-app4323.herokuapp.com
```

During the first build, the process went smoothly and i could see messages as the app was being built.

On compiling a different app, i cannot see the build messages anymore and i am thinking that the system thinks,i am still building the same application.

Where is the build information cached so that i can clean it after every build?.My app is made in meteor and cordova.

Answer (score 0):

The  build cache is located at .meteor/local/bundler-cache .